# MSVCR90.dll profiling in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling, msvcr90.dll

I've recently started playing around with the Microsoft Visual Studio Team System Profiler.

All worked well except for a few strange results. The profiler tells me that a lot of the execution bottleneck has to to with the MSVCR90.dll.

Could this be an accurate result? What's inside this dll that might consume so much of my execution time?

I suspect that a matrix library that I'm using (MTL4) does some memory allocation and copying in the background and maybe that's the problem. Is this dll somehow responsible with memory allocation and moving data arownd?

Comment: Unless you show some code, the question is open-ended and unsolvable.

Comment: Are you by any chance looking at "self time"? If you are, don't. It's a misleading and worthless statistic that's only in there because the myth that it's useful has been taught for 30 years. Look at *inclusive percent*, and look at *your* routines, not system functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it contains the functions from the compiler's standard library.

`malloc` would be one of those, so it can certainly be involved in memory allocation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I'll have to dig deeper to find the real problem. Yeey! That's gonna be a real treat.